# jQuery AJAX behaving differently with normal form & call in a div based popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When submitting the form based on normal method it execute jQuery AJAX perfectly. When submitting the same form used within the popup the jQuery AJAX is not executed. Why is that? The code is given below.

**Form submission script:**

```
$("#submit").click(function (e) {
    /* $('form').submit(function() { // bind function to submit event of form   */
    if ($('form').attr('rel') == 'frm_jquery') {

        $('#result')
                .html('<span id="process">processing....</span>');

        $.ajax({
            type: $('form').attr('method'), // get type of request from 'method'
            url: $('form').attr('action'), // get url of request from 'action'
            data: $('form').serialize(), // serialize the form's data
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status == 'success') {
                    $('form')[0].reset();
                    $('#result').html(data.message);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#result').fadeOut('fast');
                        if (data.url != undefined)
                            window.location.replace(data.url);
                    }, 5000);
                }
                else if (data.status == 'error') {
                    $('#result').html(data.message);
                }
                else if (data.status == 'redirect') {
                    window.location.replace(data.url);
                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false; // important: prevent the form from submitting
    }
});
```

**Popup script:**

```
$('.pop').click(function () {
    var src = $(this).attr('href'); //store url to variable
    var width = (($(this).attr('data-popwidth') != undefined) ? $(this).attr('data-popwidth') : 600);
    var height = (($(this).attr('data-popheight') != undefined) ? $(this).attr('data-popheight') : 500);
    if ($(window).width() < width) {
        width = "98%";
        var left_pos = "1%";
    }
    else {
        var left_pos = ($(window).width() - width) / 2 + 'px';
        width = width + "px";
    }
    if ($(window).height() < height) {
        height = "98%";
        var top_pos = "1%";
    }
    else {
        var top_pos = ($(window).height() - height) / 2 + 'px';
        height = height + "px";
    }
    $('#dv_move').remove();
    //add to body
    $('<div></div>')
            .prependTo('body')
            .attr('id', 'overlay');// add overlay div to disable the parent page

    var title = 'test';
    var html = '<div class="main" id="dv_move"  style="width:' + width + '; height:' + height + ';  left:' + left_pos + '; top:' + top_pos + '">';
    html += '<div id="dv_no_move" style="overflow-y: scroll;">';
    html += ' </div>';
    html += ' </div>';
    $('body').append(html);
    $("#dv_no_move").load(src);

    $("#img_close").click(function () {
        $('#overlay').fadeOut('slow');
        $('#dv_move').fadeOut('slow');
        setTimeout("$('#dv_move').remove();", 1000);
        //call Refresh(); if we need to reload the parent page on its closing
        parent.Refresh();
    });

    $("#img_close").mousedown(function () {
        return false;
    });
    //change close icon image on hover
    $("#img_close").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).css('opacity', '0.6');
        //            $(this).attr("src", 'close.png');
    });
    $("#img_close").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).css('opacity', '1');
        //            $(this).attr("src", 'close-red.png');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What is in the code `src` that is being loaded? Where is the form submission script? Are they both in the same file?

Comment: src is a normal html form file. the form is working fine in normal submission. if call on using popup src, it accepted bit the jquery onclick event $('.pop').click(function() not executing

Comment: Is the first of your two code blocks (form submission script) in the "normal html form file" you load with `$("#dv_no_move").load(src);`, or is it in the same file as your second code block (popup script) that does the loading?

Comment: give some time i will upload the script in server and provide the link

Comment: the demo uploaded on server - the link is http://orloninc.com/test/ .   to download the entire files http://orloninc.com/test/popup.rar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you attach the event handler to `#submit`. At that time, the form is not yet loaded, so the event handler isn't attached to anything. After that (when the user clicks on the link) the form is opened in a popup. There is no event handler attached to `#submit`, since that code ran before `#submit` was created. Therefore nothing happens when you click it.

So how do you fix it? You need to attach the event handler *after* the form is loaded:

```
$("#dv_no_move").load(src, function() {
     //This code will run when the content has been loaded into the div.
     //Here we can attach the event handler to #submit.
     $("#submit").click(function(e) {
          //The code to do stuff when #submit is clicked should be placed here.
     });
});
```

Please note that this will attach the event handler to `#submit` no matter what it is that is loaded. Perhaps you use the same page to load other pages as well where you don't want this behavior? Then the above code will be problematic.

Instead, you could put the JavaScript for the submit button in the page that clicking the popup loads (the one with address `src`), or include it from there. I think you should also wrap it in `$(function() { ... }`.